# wpf referencing value converter from within nested datatemplate (causing null reference exception)

Tags: wpf, nested, datatemplate, nullreferenceexception, ivalueconverter

I am experiencing troubles with IValueConverters called from **nested datatemplate** (ListViewItems).

I have complex (list of) objects containing other objects and lists of lists of objects (too much source code to put it all here)...

Everything works fine except the IValueConverter Implementation on deeper nesting levels...

Simplifyed and shortened XAML:

```
    <Window x:Class="XXXX.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:XXXX.Converter"
    Width="800"
    Height="600"
    Icon="/Images/Icons/Calendar.ico"
    Loaded="Window_Loaded"
    Style="{StaticResource WindowDefaultStyle}"
    WindowState="Maximized">
<Window.Resources>
    <!--  <converter:ValueToVisibilityConverter x:Key="ValueToVisibility" />  -->
    <converter:PercentageConverter x:Key="PercentFromValue" />
    <converter:SubtractionConverter x:Key="SubstractFromValue" />
    <converter:SingleTextLineConverter x:Key="inSingleLine" />
    <converter:B2VConverter x:Key="B2V" />
</Window.Resources>

    <Grid Name="grid_Supplier">
        <ListView Name="listview_Product"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Height="{Binding ElementName=grid_Supplier,
            Path=ActualHeight,
            Converter={StaticResource SubstractFromValue},
            ConverterParameter=60}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
            AncestorType=Window},Path=SuppliersProducts}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ListView Name="listview_CM"
                                Width="{Binding ElementName=grid_SupplierProduct,
                                Path=ActualWidth,
                                Converter={StaticResource PercentFromValue},
                                ConverterParameter=80}"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding CM}">
                                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <ListView Name="listview_Comments"
                                            ItemsSource="{Binding Comments}">
                                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                                <DataTemplate>
                                                    <TextBlock
                                                            Text="{Binding Comment.DueDate, StringFormat='dd.MM.yyyy'}"
                                                            Background="{Binding Status
```

**, Converter={StaticResource B2V}**

```
}"/>
                                                </DataTemplate>
                                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                        </ListView>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListView>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

as you can see there are 3 nested ListViews, the converter (PercentFromValue) in the "first" level is working without problems - with Binding and Parameter...

My problem are at the next nesting "levels" as soon as the Converter part (**StaticResource B2V**) of the Binding is present, Null reference exception is risen at Runtime (no further explanations or nested exception infos are available... - but as soon as the converter is gone there is no problem... OK no exception, but also no Background - as has to be expected... )

I have tried to create "listview resource" part, but there is also Null reference exception risen (I assume the "converter:" part of the path can not be found in that case.

Since I am using Backgroundworker (information shown on the gui is collected from more than 9 related tables), there is no possibility to pass Brush to the gui (inherits from Dispatcher and causes "DependencySource must be created in same thread as DependencyProperty" Error).

Now I am preparing all in the Background and adding only the Background-Brush in the same thread as workaround, but it is ugly...

It will be much better to use the converter, but **how to reference it from within the nested datatemplate?**

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I have solved it myself with moving the DataTemplates in the Window.Resources and making them refererence each other, thus creating "flat" structure not directly nested anymore...

```
<Window x:Class="XXXX.MainWindow"
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
   xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:XXXX.Converter"
   Width="800"
   Height="600"
   Icon="/Images/Icons/Calendar.ico"
   Loaded="Window_Loaded"
   Style="{StaticResource WindowDefaultStyle}"
   WindowState="Maximized">
<Window.Resources>
   <converter:PercentageConverter x:Key="PercentFromValue" />
   <converter:SubtractionConverter x:Key="SubstractFromValue" />
   <converter:SingleTextLineConverter x:Key="inSingleLine" />
   <converter:B2VConverter x:Key="B2V" />

   <DataTemplate x:Key="CommentTemplate">
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Comment.DueDate, StringFormat='dd.MM.yyyy'}" Background="{Binding Status, Converter={StaticResource B2V}}"
   </DataTemplate>

   <DataTemplate x:Key="CommentsTemplate">
<ListView Name="listview_Comments"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Comments}"
            ItemTemplate={StaticResource CommentTemplate} />
   </DataTemplate>


   <DataTemplate x:Key="CMTemplate">
        <ListView Name="listview_CM"
        Width="{Binding ElementName=grid_SupplierProduct,
        Path=ActualWidth,
        Converter={StaticResource PercentFromValue},
        ConverterParameter=80}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding CM}"
        ItemTemplate={StaticResource CommentsTemplate} />
   </DataTemplate>

</Window.Resources>

<Grid Name="grid_Supplier">
    <ListView Name="listview_Product"
        Grid.Row="1"
        Height="{Binding ElementName=grid_Supplier,
        Path=ActualHeight, Converter={StaticResource SubstractFromValue},
        ConverterParameter=60}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
        AncestorType=Window},Path=SuppliersProducts}"
        ItemTemplate={StaticResource CMTemplate}/>
</Grid>
```

Take care that the innermost template is defined as the first and so on. Otherwise the templates will not be found.

Due to this structuring of the file we have all "flat" on one level and the converters are found and referenced.